# AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'mean'

Tags: dataframe, variables, ipython

I am encountering an error that I can't get out of:

I have separated my columns according to the unique values of the variables:

```
cats_df = df.columns[df.nunique() < 6]
num_df = df.columns[df.nunique()>= 6]
```

And I wanted to replace the missing values of the numerical columns >= 6 with the average:

```
num_df = num_df.fillna(num_df.mean())
```

But I get this error message :

```
AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last) 
<ipython-input-22-59bfd4048c41> in <module> ----> 1 num_df = num_df.fillna(num_df.mean()) 2 num_df 
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'mean'
```

Can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: Can you add the entire traceback please?

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-59bfd4048c41> in <module>
----> 1 num_df = num_df.fillna(num_df.mean())
      2 num_df

AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'mean'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that num_df is an index, not a dataframe, you may need something like this:

```
num_df = df[df.columns[df.nunique()>= 6]]
num_df = num_df.fillna(num_df.mean())
```